# Check if directory exists using home character (~) in bash fails

Tags: bash

Why does the following `bash` check if a directory fail?

```
if [ ! -d "~/Desktop" ]; then
   echo "DOES NOT EXIST"
   exit 1;
fi
```

`~/Desktop` does indeed exist. This is on a Mac by the way.

---

The problem is with this type of script

```
read -p "Provide the destination directory: " DESTINATION

if [ ! -d $DESTINATION ]; then
    echo "\t'$DESTINATION' does not exist." >&2;
    exit 1;
fi
```

Comment: Just like when you do `cd "~/Desktop"` you also get an error. It has to be unquoted or stored as a variable (without quotes). For example, `a=~/Desktop; cd $a;` works but not `a="~/Desktop"; cd Desktop;` See http://serverfault.com/questions/417252/check-if-directory-exists-using-home-character-in-bash-fails/482695#482695

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Justin clarified his question in his first comment on quanta's answer.  He is reading in a line of text using `read` (or by some other dynamic means) and wants to expand the tilde.

The question becomes "How do you perform tilde expansion on the contents of a variable?"

The general approach is to use `eval`, but it comes with some important caveats, namely spaces and output redirection (`>`) in the variable.  The following seems to work for me:

```
read -p "Provide the destination directory: " DESTINATION

if [ ! -d "`eval echo ${DESTINATION//>}`" ]; then
    echo "'$DESTINATION' does not exist." >&2;
    exit 1;
fi
```

Try it with each of the following inputs:

```
~
~/existing_dir
~/existing dir with spaces
~/nonexistant_dir
~/nonexistant dir with spaces
~/string containing > redirection
~/string containing > redirection > again and >> again
```

#### Explanation

- The `${mypath//>}` strips out `>` characters which could clobber a file during the `eval`.
- The `eval echo ...` is what does the actual tilde expansion
- The double-quotes around the `eval` are for support of filenames with spaces.

As a supplement to this, you can improve the UX by adding the `-e` option to read:

```
read -p "Provide the destination directory: " -e DESTINATION
```

Now when the user types in tilde and hits tab, it will expand.  This approach does not *replace* the eval approach above, however, as the expansion only happens if the user hits tab.   If he just types in ~/foo and hits enter, it will remain as a tilde.

See also:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963716/how-to-manually-expand-a-special-variable-ex-tilde-in-bash

Answer (score 26):

Remove the double quotes around the directory to see if it works:

```
if [ ! -d ~/Desktop ]; then
   echo "DOES NOT EXIST"
   exit 1;
fi
```

The reason for it is tilde expansion only works when it is unquoted.

**`info "(bash) Tilde Expansion"`**

```
3.5.2 Tilde Expansion
---------------------

If a word begins with an unquoted tilde character (`~'), all of the
characters up to the first unquoted slash (or all characters, if there
is no unquoted slash) are considered a TILDE-PREFIX.  If none of the
characters in the tilde-prefix are quoted, the characters in the
tilde-prefix following the tilde are treated as a possible LOGIN NAME.
If this login name is the null string, the tilde is replaced with the
value of the `HOME' shell variable.  If `HOME' is unset, the home
directory of the user executing the shell is substituted instead.
Otherwise, the tilde-prefix is replaced with the home directory
associated with the specified login name.
```

Comment: How about if the value comes in dynamically. I.e. (http://pastie.org/4471350) and `DESTINATION` is `~/Desktop`.

Comment: Tilde-expansion is done when the variable is set, not when it's evaluated, so that's not a fair example.

Comment: +1, this is enough to solve my problem.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't work not only on Mac but on any platform that runs bash on.

When you quote "~/Desktop" you are telling bash to look for Desktop inside the ~ folder. The quote removes the special purpose of ~

See -- http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Tilde-Expansion

Remove the double quotes and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

run

```
echo $HOME
```

use `$HOME`, and make sure the user is actually using the script.  if root uses `~` its going to look in `/root`, not `/home/$USER`.

```
if [ ! -d "$HOME/Desktop" ]; then
   echo "DOES NOT EXIST"
   exit 1;
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if [ ! -d "$HOME/Desktop" ]; then
   echo "DOES NOT EXIST"
   exit 1;
fi
```

should be $HOME instead of ~

~ is a KEYBOARD thing

Comment: If you read the other answer here you would realize this is wrong.